# Exported Google Slides presentation does not include recent changes

Tags: google-apps-script, export-to-pdf, google-slides-api

I have written some code to automatically add in a user's name to a template Google Slides file. This template is essentially a certificate, and I'm trying to automate the generation of said certificate for each user.

Unfortunately, when I try to convert the Slides file to a PDF, it converts the slide without the user's name - e.g. basically just the template file is exported. It's definitely pulling in the correct file id, but still not working. The only problem I can think of is that the presentation hasn't saved the changes by the time the code gets the blob data from `DriveApp`.

```
function buildCertificate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'),
      rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(),
      template = DriveApp.getFileById('some file id'),
      destination = DriveApp.getFolderById('some folder id'),
      i = 1;

  while (i < rows.length) {
    if (rows[i][3] != 'Y') {
      var file = template.makeCopy(rows[i][0] + ' ' + rows[i][1], destination),
      id = file.getId(),
      slide = SlidesApp.openById(id).getSlides()[0],
      shape = slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, 60, 207, 600, 110),
      textRange = shape.getText(),
      textStyle = textRange.getTextStyle();

      textRange.setText([rows[i][0] + ' ' + rows[i][1]]);
      textStyle.setFontSize(40);
      textStyle.setForegroundColor('#F9B300');

      var paragraphStyle = textRange.getParagraphs()[0].getRange().getParagraphStyle();
      paragraphStyle.setParagraphAlignment(SlidesApp.ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

      var theBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName('test'),
      newFile = DriveApp.getFolderById("some folder id").createFile(theBlob);
    }

    sheet.getRange(i + 1, 4).setValue('Y');
    i++;
  } 
}
```

Comment: You need to close the open presentation to flush pending writes before you acquire the file data with `DriveApp`

Comment: Try adding saveandclose() method on slidesapp object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the Apps Script `SlidesApp` documentation, you can force any pending writes to the Slides `Presentation` by closing it with [`saveAndClose()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#saveAndClose()). Closing of open presentations is automatically performed when the script execution ends, but for use cases such as yours, this automatic flush occurs too late to be useful:

> **`saveAndClose()`:**
> saves the current `Presentation`. Causes pending updates to be flushed and applied.
>   
>   The `saveAndClose()` method is automatically invoked at the end of script execution for each open `Presentation`, even if the script execution terminated with an error.
>   
>   A closed `Presentation` cannot be edited. Use one of the open methods on `SlidesApp` to reopen a given presentation for editing.

The presentation your code uses is bound in your variable `slide`, so altering your loop structure to close this prior to your `DriveApp` code will ensure the `Blob` data reflects the latest changes.

```
while (i < rows.length) {
  if (rows[i][3] != 'Y') {
    var file = template.makeCopy(rows[i][0] + ' ' + rows[i][1], destination),
        id = file.getId(),
        presentation = SlidesApp.openById(id),
        slide = presentation.getSlides()[0],
        shape = slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, 60, 207, 600, 110),
        textRange = shape.getText(),
        textStyle = textRange.getTextStyle();

    textRange.setText([rows[i][0] + ' ' + rows[i][1]]);
    textStyle.setFontSize(40);
    textStyle.setForegroundColor('#F9B300');

    var paragraphStyle = textRange.getParagraphs()[0].getRange().getParagraphStyle();
    paragraphStyle.setParagraphAlignment(SlidesApp.ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

    // Flush the changes we've made to the instantiated template presentation.
    presentation.saveAndClose();

    // Reopen the file with DriveApp -- could perhaps use the existing `file` reference, e.g.:
    // var theBlob = file.getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName('test');
    var theBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName('test');
    // Create the PDF in the desired Drive folder.
    DriveApp.getFolderById("some folder id").createFile(theBlob);
  }

  sheet.getRange(i + 1, 4).setValue('Y');
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As was said in the comments, you're not saving and closing the file after making the changes.

Replace the line:

```
slide = SlidesApp.openById(id).getSlides()[0],
```

with

```
file = SlidesApp.openById(id),
slide = file.getSlides()[0],
```

After the line

```
 paragraphStyle.setParagraphAlignment(SlidesApp.ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
```

Add the line

```
 file.saveAndClose();
```